# Delete task always UP-TO-DATE

Tags: gradle, build

I've a simple task in Gradle:

```
task cleanBuild(type: Delete) {
    def build = ".src/buildfiles"
    FileTree tree = fileTree (dir: dbEditorBuild);
    tree.each { File file ->
        println file
    }
}
```

When I run it, I get this output:

```
:user:cleanBuild UP-TO-DATE
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1.656 secs
```

I've read the docs and it says that tasks results are cached for performance. I wanted to rerun the task, but I couldn't. And that was despite editing the task code. So, apparently, it seems that Gradle is not able to detect that the task has been changed, which kind of suck.

I've tried what others recommended, like adding this line to the task:

```
outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
```

But it doesn't have any effect.

Comment: What do you expect the task to do?

Comment: I'm expecting the task result not to be cached by Gradle. I'm experimenting with writing a task. Previously I wanted to delete all files(including directories) in the tree under the variable `build`, but the method `delete` seemed to delete only plain files (not directories).

Comment: The result is not cached, there is simply nothing to do for your task, since you did not specify any files to delete. I assume that your file tree does not find any files at all.

Comment: After all, as you know the answer now, can you please amend your question to fit the @lu.koerfer answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You define a task of the type `Delete`, but you don't define any files to delete. That is the reason, why your task is always up-to-date, since it has nothing to do. You can define which files will be deleted via the [`delete`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Delete.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Delete:delete(java.lang.Object[])) method. Everything you pass to this method will be evaluated via [`Project.files(...)`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:files(java.lang.Object[])):

```
task myDelete(type: Delete) {
    delete 'path/to/file', 'path/to/other/file'
}
```

Please note, that your code example does not interfere with the up-to-date checks, it doesn't even interfere with the task at all. Since you are not using a `doFirst`/`doLast` closure, you are using the configuration closure of the task, which is executed during *configuration phase*. Since you are also not using any task methods, your code would mean absolutely the same if it would be placed outside of the task configuration closure.

As a small addition: Even if this specific problem is not caused by the Gradle up-to-date checks, there is a way to force Gradle to execute all tasks ignoring any task optimization: Simply add `--rerun-tasks` as command line argument, as described in [the docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_command_line.html).

Comment: True, I assumed there is a different task ran before this one.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to delete some additional files that are not deleted with a default `clean` task (because it deletes only the `build` directories) you can extend the clean task to delete other things as well.

```
clean {
    delete += "$buildDir"
    delete += "$rootDir/someDir/someClass.java"
    delete += "$rootDir/otherDir
}
```

Or create a new task to [delete](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Delete.html) files and dependOn it to put in the build lifecycle.

```
task deleteSomething(type: Delete) {
    // to delete a file
    delete 'uglyFolder', 'uglyFile' 
    // to delete a directory
    delete 'uglyFolder'
    followSymlinks = true
}
```

> Be default symlinks will not be followed when deleting files. To change this behavior call Delete.setFollowSymlinks(boolean) with true. On systems that do not support symlinks, this will have no effect.

Or you can put the action into the execution phase, and delete it.

```
task cleanBuild {
    def build = new File("$rootDir/src/buildfiles")
    doLast{
      build.deleteDir()
    }
}
```

Also, be sure the task has something to do because if the task has nothing to do, there is nothing to delete etc it will print UP-TO-DATE @lu.koerfer answer explains it perfectly.

Comment: While the end goal is to remove some files, this is not exactly what I want, though. I want the task to be run again by Gradle.

Comment: @Ammaro if your task is UP-TO-DATE that means the outputs/inputs didn't changes or the task is simply doing nothing.

Comment: I changed the task code, but it still it says that it is up-to-date. Why is that?

Comment: Because your code has nothing to do with the task at all.

Comment: Maybe there is nothing to do, nothing to delete or the directory simply doesn't exist.

Comment: Yeah. The problem was my task was of type Delete and it was not doing any deletion, so after each run, Gradle assumed it has not changed. Thanks anyway.